# Explicitly rounding numbers to more than 7 decimal places in C++

Tags: c++, numbers, rounding

Here is my code:

```
double round( char* strNumber, int decPlace);

int main()
{
    int decimal;
         char initialNumber[256];

    cout << "Enter decimal and number " << endl;

    cin >> decimal;
    cin >> initialNumber;

    cout << setprecision (15) << round ( initialNumber,decimal ) << endl;   

return 0;
}

double round( char* strNumber, int decPlace)//
{
    double number = atof(strNumber);
    int temp = ( int ) ( pow(10.0,decPlace) * number + 0.5 );
    double result = ( double ) temp / pow(10.0,decPlace);
    return result;
}
```

It works up to 6 decimal places. Otherwise it gives some strange result. Below are numbers that I used for testing and the output:

Test 1-round to 7 decimal places

```
105.265

52.5689745694

25.6835

452.689785

12.456789877458
```

Output

```
105.265

52.5689746

25.6835

-214.7483648

12.4567899
```

Test 1-round to 8 decimal places

The same numbers as previously

Output

```
-21.47483648

-21.47483648

-21.47483648

-21.47483648

12.45678988
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said, the cast to int won't work with large numbers. You could consider using `floor` instead, and keeping the number to be rounded in a `double`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

double round( char* strNumber, int decPlace)
{
    double number = std::atof(strNumber);
    double expo = std::pow(10.0,decPlace);
    return std::floor( expo * number + 0.5) / expo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`int` can hold a smaller range than `double`; on many platforms its maximum value is about 2 billion, which is less than `pow(10.0,8) * number` for most of your input numbers.

You could keep your number as a `double` and use `floor` to round down to an integer:

```
double temp = floor( pow(10.0,decPlace) * number + 0.5 );
double result = temp / pow(10.0,decPlace);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int temp = ( int ) ( pow(10.0,decPlace) * number + 0.5 );
```

temp is probably 32 bits. It can hold up about +- 2 billion. Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow). `pow(10.0,decPlace) * number` is a pretty large number - too large to fit in a 32 bit integer (which is what `int` probably is on your platform).